# Double saved as int in PostgreSql Database using CASE-WHEN

Tags: c#, postgresql

I have a problem updating a table. The number 3,25 is saved as 325. This happens only if i use this UPDATE:

```
using(var con = new Npgsql.NpgsqlConnection(constr))
{
 var UpdCmd = "UPDATE \"Haus\".\"Category\" SET \"Value\" = 
 CASE "+" WHEN \"CategoryID\"=" + 1 + " THEN " + 3.25 +
 " WHEN \"CategoryID\"=" + 2 + " THEN " + 2.25 +" END ";

con.Open();

Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand command = new Npgsql.NpgsqlCommand(UpdCmd, con);
command.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

valueCategoryA and valueCategoryB are both of type double. If i use simple Update without CASE i dont have this problem.

**EDIT** :
I get same result with query parameters too. And it doesn't matter if i use 3,25 or 3.25. The result is always 325

Comment: Stop building queries by concatenating strings and start using query parameters. Why do you think "3,25" is a valid format for double anyway? Please give links to the relevant parts of the manuals to support your thinking.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to use the driver's parameter passing, and you should, then at least format it as:

```
string UpdCmd = String.Format(@"
    UPDATE ""Haus"".""Category""
    SET ""Value"" = CASE ""CategoryID""
        WHEN 1 THEN {0}
        WHEN 2 THEN {1}
        END
    ", valueCategoryA, valueCategoryB);
```

The double quote escapes another double quote inside a raw (@) string. In a raw string you can have a multi line string. That and the `Format` method makes it much more readable.

Why use `var` if you know it is a string?

Comment: I still get only integer. Is there any alternative to CASE?

Comment: @Georg Your problem is not the `CASE`. Show the code where you set those variables. Display the variable `UpdCmd` to see what it really contains. Use the debugger for that.

Comment: @Clodaledo even if i set the numbers directly in the UpdCmd i still get integer. I edited my code

Comment: @Georg Try it as `THEN " + "3.25" +`, that is, the number inside double quotes.